# how to round down inf values

Tags: python, dataframe, inf

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to calculate some averages, however the result is often an `inf` value, which is messing up my dataframe. Is it possible to round down the `inf` value in Python?

Some example of code:

```
df['Htgs/2'] = df.groupby('Home Team', ) ['Hg'].rolling(window=a, min_periods=a ).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df['Htgs/2']= (((df['Htgs/2'] * a) - df['Hg']) / (a-1)) / df['Lha']
df['Agcr/2'] = df.groupby('Away Team', ) ['Agcr'].rolling(window=a, min_periods=a ).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df['Agsr/2']= (((df['Agcr/2'] * a) - df['Agcr']) / (a-1))
df = df.round(decimals=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well it would work in your use-case overall, but you can replace the `inf` values with an arbitrarily large number:

```
df_new = df.replace( [ inf, -inf ], 1e99 )
print( df_new )
```

Without knowing your exact dataframe, this is only a rough example. You're going to have to modify it to fit your data and criteria.

Comment: The `.replace` function doesn't replace in place. I edited it a bit, so maybe it'll work now

Answer (score 0):

you could do this to just not consider the inf

```
df[df['your_column'] != np.inf].mean()
```